# Intersection of contractible spaces is contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given that the intersection is nonempty, is it true?

Can I argue that if $1_U$ and $1_V$ are null-homotopic, then $1_{U\cap V}$ is null homotopic as well? Also, I'm assuming that $U$ and $V$ are path connected(though I don't know if they matter)

Comment: No. Consider two circular arcs on the circle, which are contractible but whose intersection can have two connected components. In fact the intersection of two contractible (sub)spaces can have arbitrary homotopy type. Take a double cone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)

Comment: If I add the condition that $U$ and $V$ are also path-connected, would it follow?

Comment: No. Circular arcs are path-connected, and contractible spaces are already automatically path-connected.

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Trivial case: $U,V$ are disjoint. Then $\emptyset$ is not contractible.

Comment: Intersection is not empty. If $U$ and $V$ deformation retracts to the same point, then is the intersection of them contractible?

Comment: @able20 No, the example of the arcs on the circle still works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $U = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1, y \ge 0 \}$ and $V = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1, y \le 0 \}$. These sets describe the upper and lower half of the unit circle in the plane. Both contain $\{(1,0)\}$ as a strong deformation  retract, but $U  \cap V = \{(1,0), (-1,0)\}$ is not contractible. Note that also $U \cup V$ is not contractible.